# How to perform jsf action using html 5 button

Tags: html, jsf, seam3

How do we use html 5 button tag to perform jsf action 
eg.

to perform

```
<h:commandButton action="#{identity.login}" value="Login"/>
```

what will be the equivalent in html 5 ??

Comment: The standard JSF component suite currently does not render any HTML5 output.  That doesn't mean that JSF won't support HTML5, just that there is a lack of a good JSF/HTML5 component suite currently available. You would have to write your own JSF component. Check out Primefaces though because they have a few components that render HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a custom facelet component to wrapper a html5 element yourself.

Another project, [omnifaces](http://omnifaces.org) provides html5 compatibility for current jsf components.

Answer (score 0):

<input jsf:id="do-search-button" type="submit" jsf:action="#{searchController.doSearch}" class="search-button" title="#{msg.search_tooltip}" value="#{msg.search_button}" />